# How can I input password only once when gpg decrypt files in batch

Tags: password, gpg

I want decrypt some gpg files, output into a file. But each time gpg ask password.

```
for i in *.gpg; do echo $i>>~/t; gpg -d --batch $i >>~/t; done
```

I test --multifile and --batch, those not as my wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways:

```bsh
# gather the password into $P
stty -echo; read -r P; stty echo; 
for i in *.gpg; do printf '%s\n' "$i" >> ~/t; printf '%s' | gpg -d --batch --passphrase-fd 0 "$i" >> ~/t; done

# gather the password into $P
stty -echo; read -r P; stty echo; 
for i in *.gpg; do printf '%s\n' "$i" >> ~/t; gpg -d --batch --passphrase "$P" "$i" >> ~/t; done

d=$(mktemp -d)
# gather the password into a file named `p`
stty -echo; cat > "$d/p"; stty echo
for i in *.gpg; do printf '%s\n' "$i" >> ~/t; gpg -d --batch --passphrase-file "$d/p" 0 "$i" >> ~/t; done
rm -rf "$d"
```